# Синхронизация Баз Данных на телефоне и на сервере

Tags: android, база-данных, синхронизация

Я пытаюсь сделать справочник на Android. В нём есть БД, и я хочу, чтобы эта база данных заполнялась через данные в интернете. Т.е. я изменяю какой-либо файл в интернете и при нажатии на кнопку в приложении, база данных приложения заполнялась данными из файла в интернете.

P.S. я думал насчёт сохранения текста на облаке или же бд на облаке, а потом его синхронизация. Заранее Спасибо!

P.S.S. Я хочу чтобы приложение могло работать offline, поэтому мне достаточно будет, если кто-то напишет как осуществить загрузку файла из интернета в определенную папку.

Comment: Да, стоило сразу уточнить что вы хотели.

Answer (score 1):

Сразу приходят 2 варианта:

1. Отслеживание изменений в БД (возможность БД).
2. Передача

   2.1 JSON

   2.2 клиент-сервер (TCPIP)

Поясню. На клиенте (телефоне) хранится БД и её версия изменений (переменная из отслеживания изменений в БД на сервере) раз в N секунд происходит запрос на сервер (тут вариантов много. Начиная от post http запроса и заканчивая своим клиент-серверным приложением) сервер смотрит версию на клиенте и берет новые строки из БД с новой версией изменения и посылает строки с указанием версии клиенту... Клиент парсит и обновляет у себя строки и версию изменений